# why isn't my application reaching the console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, middleware

I have the following function located in cr-route.js that makes sure that the user is authenticated before proceeding and displays his name

```
module.exports = function (app, passport) {

    // =====================================
    // HOME PAGE (with login links) ========
    // =====================================
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
    });

    // =====================================
    // LOGIN ===============================
    // =====================================
    // show the login form
    app.route('/login')
        .get(function (req, res) {

            // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
            res.render('login.ejs', {
                message: req.flash('loginMessage')
            });
        })

        // process the login form
        .post(passport.authenticate('local-login', {
                successRedirect: '/home', // redirect to the secure profile section
                failureRedirect: '/', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
                failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
            }),
            function (req, res) {
                console.log("hello");


                if (req.body.remember) {
                    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
                } else {
                    req.session.cookie.expires = false;
                }
                res.redirect('/');
            });

    // =====================================
    // SIGNUP ==============================
    // =====================================
    // show the signup form
    app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs', {message: req.flash('signupMessage')});
    });

    // process the signup form
    app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect: '/home', // redirect to the secure home section
        failureRedirect: '/', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
    }));

    // =====================================
    // Home SECTION =========================
    // =====================================
    // we will want this protected so you have to be logged in to visit
    // we will use route middleware to verify this (the isLoggedIn function)
    app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        res.render('home.ejs', {
            title: 'C',
            user: req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });

    // =====================================
    // LOGOUT ==============================
    // =====================================
    app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```

I am calling this route from the following module located at home.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var url = require('url');
var passport = require('passport');


    module.exports = function (app) {
        require('../app/cr-route')(app, passport);
        app.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
            var queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
            console.log('im in'); //not displaying

        });
        return router;
    };
```

then I am calling this module from app.js file by issuing the following:

```
require('./routes/home')(app);
```

But I have a feeling that although I am able to successfully load the home.js, it's still not accessing the get method inside of it.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have the same route, `/home`, defined in `cr-route.js` and `home.js`. I assume the one in `home.js` never get called because it was already handled in `cr-route.js`